# Raspicam throws segmentation fault after 2nd retrieve (C++)

Tags: camera, raspicam, opencv, c++

I have a script that continuously takes small pictures and compares the green channel, but when getting the 2nd picture it throws Segmentation fault.
http://pastebin.com/CaUhSdP6 (line 37)

Comment: Please create a minimal, verifiable example and include it in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it by not performing the snap in separate function, moved it to motion_sensing_loop(..)